# CocoaPods on M1 (Apple Silicon) fails with ffi wrong architecture

Tags: cocoapods, ffi, apple-m1, rosetta

Running 'pod install' on a M1 MacBook failed for me due to an ffi issue, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/64901980).

I followed some of the workarounds (I guess I tried all of them in various order), but now I get a slightly different error:

```
LoadError - dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle
```

So, it seems I now have ffi, but with a wrong architecture? How can I fix this? This happens with/without running the terminal in Rosetta mode.

One of the proposed workarounds did not succeed for me, by the way. When I try:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

I get:

```
arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Not sure if this is related.

Answer (score 144):

Answering my own question. I fixed the ffi issue by uninstalling my faulty Ruby version and CocoaPods, then I used the -x86_64 arch to reinstall ffi and CocoaPods.

These are the steps I did to get back to a working state (and to apply the M1 workarounds for ffi):

1. Uninstall Ruby with: `brew uninstall ruby --force`
2. Uninstall CocoaPods. At first, try to list all CocoaPods versions / components with `gem list --local | grep cocoapods`. Then uninstall them one by one, in my case:

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core`

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader`

etc.

3. As a next step I was able to reinstall ffi and then CocoaPods with:

`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods`

Once done, I could run `pod install` as expected. Note that I had the Terminal open all the time in standard mode - no Rosetta required.

Comment: Finally i found this solution works, I tried everything, from installing new version of ruby with rbenv, updating all dependencies. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem perfectly. Very grateful!

Comment: Thanks, solved it perfectly for the MacBook air m1 flutter project setup.

Comment: THIS is the solution!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ruby is required instead of brew uninstall ruby --force

Comment: it didn't help me on my M1

Comment: This worked for me! Note: You should **NOT** change the arch param from `-x86_64` to `-arm64` (like I did) to get it working on your Apple Silicon machine.

Comment: After browsing so many threads this step finally did it for me: `brew uninstall ruby --force`. Thank you!

Comment: Not working, new error - `Cocoapods not installed or not in valid state`.

Comment: Through what black magic did you discover this was the problem? Every other day I run into issues like this where the actual root of the issue is barely related to the error given. I always just end up trawling the internet until I find a seemingly arbitrary solution.

Comment: Thanks. All these steps helped. I had to change `pod install` to `arch -x86_64 pod install` to get it work on my m2.
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037887/2106941

Comment: I had to completely delete rvm to get it to install correctly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I have been using Roseta since 2021 and never knew a solution like this existed. It worked for me

Comment: Maybe one can also consider calling `gem update` and `bundle update` afterwards

Answer (score 44):

As said Datasun I removed cocoapods

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo gem uninstall
```

and then run:

```
brew remove rbenv
sudo rm -rf ~/.rbenv
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods
brew install rbenv
rbenv install 3.0.1
rbenv global 3.0.1

pod install
```

without any problem.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for making it easier to copy and paste

Comment: For posterity for anyone trying the above and receiving the `no podfile` error, I ran the above excluding `pod install` then ran `bundle install` and now running smooth

Comment: This still fails: `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`.  Any other command to try?

Comment: you save my day, but I using Mac with an M1 chip and before install rbenv 3.0.1, I following steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66128681/ruby-build-failed-macos-11-2-using-ruby-build-20210119-mac-big-sur

Comment: this solution didn't help me, i am using an M1

Comment: This worked for me on Macbook Pro with Apple M1 Pro.

Comment: I also had to remove the Pods dir and Podfile.lock

Comment: In case you have issues with linking to openssl or gem install errors. Try installing openssl from brew and linking to it as per: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/377#issuecomment-21014365

Answer (score 32):

I agree with Datasun's answer. But I managed to follow roughly the same steps which gave a a functioning outcome, that I thought to be better or just as good. I ran the lines in terminal:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ruby
```

then

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

after this I wanted to Homebrew the cocoapods so I used:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

(you may need to use reinstall)

Comment: Thanks, This is the only solution worked for me

Comment: Yes, reinstalling via brew, not gem!

Comment: Thanks alot mate! This is the only solution worked for me also.

Comment: Using homebrew to install cocoapods seems like it was the missing piece for me! Cheers!

Answer (score 17):

I tried almost everything and this was the only solution that worked for me:

uninstalling the cocoapods package through gem

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

and reinstalling it with homebrew

```
brew install cocoapods
```

fixed my problem.

The problem was I installed `cocoapods` through gem install instead of homebrew.

Answer (score 13):

I got it working by first cleaning up all previously installed pods:
`pod deintegrate`
Then installing them again using this command:
`arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: This worked for me on Mac M1

Comment: Your solution work well on Mac M1 and IPhone X ios 16.2

Answer (score 8):

I got this error while setting up capacitor project on my new macbook with m1 chip. However, if you want to use capacitor, flutter or React Native, you will get this error because this is a framework independent, computer-related problem.

Ruby and cocoapods must be installed on your computer. In my case, running the following commands one by one worked.

1.

```
brew install ruby
```

2. 

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

3. 

```
brew install cocoapods
```

and, you are ready now.

```
pod install
```

Comment: You may need to have the path to pod. `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`. ruby version may vary.

Answer (score 6):

When i tried the x86_64:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

linking shared-object ffi_c.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/libruby.3.0.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rb_ary_detransient", referenced from:
      _memory_put_array_of_int8 in AbstractMemory.o
```

so I tried:

`sudo arch -arm64e gem install ffi`

`sudo arch -arm64e gem install cocoapods`

then `pod install` worked!

I also had to run `rbenv init` and place the eval in `~/.zshrc` to get the right ruby version working.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Every other solution forced me to eventually have to use `arch -x86_64 pod install` again rather than `pod install`.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Datasun's answer. But currently we can use `arm64` instead of `x86_64` in M1 Macbook.

I reinstall `ruby` and ran the lines in terminal:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem uninstall cocoapods-core
gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader

gem uninstall ffi
gem install ffi
```

Comment: This worked for me:
1. sudo arch -arm64e gem install cocoapods
2. sudo arch -arm64e gem install ffi

Comment: I tried everything and only this worked thanks @nathanwhy !

Answer (score 4):

All I did for my case was run the following command to pod install. I didn't have to uninstall ruby or cocoapod

> arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: Indeed, just type:  arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had to do these extra things after following @Datasun:

```
brew install ruby
```

and

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

This described the exact problem that I was having. However, none of the solutions worked. In the end, this is what helped me solve the problem:

```
   brew unlink libyaml && brew link libyaml
   brew unlink openssl && brew link --force openssl
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902917/1809053

Answer (score 0):

just run this code, already fix

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

For an error: incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'), you need to do the following:

1. gem list --local | grep cocoapods | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo gem uninstall
2. sudo gem install ffi
3. sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?