# Unable to install Pod in Mac M1 pro

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-m1

I was getting this error when I tried to run pod install

```
 require': dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): 
  tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' 
  (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file), 
  '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
```

This I already did

1. I have already installed '***ffi gem***'
2. uninstall cocoapods then reinstall via brew
3. [Followed this link too but still not find any help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644365/cocoapods-on-m1-apple-silicon-fails-with-ffi-wrong-architecture)

Comment: try to reinstall `brew` itself