# arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable, i use mac M1 AIR

Tags: ruby, installation, apple-m1

i just sharing my experience use mac M1 AIR. i get error

```
arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable
```

after run

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

i get solve just run:

```
 brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ruby
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CocoaPods on M1 (Apple Silicon) fails with ffi wrong architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644365/cocoapods-on-m1-apple-silicon-fails-with-ffi-wrong-architecture)