# impossible to run flutter app with macbook m1

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods, apple-m1

Hello I buy an macbook m1 I have made a timemachine migration, I have upgrade android studio and xcode all is good. But when I try to run on my device I have first

```
error : pod out of date
```

so  I try to

flutter clean
remove pods folder and podfile.lock

```
pod repo update
```

but I have

Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)

SO I have try

```
 sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

but now I can't install cocoapods

i have  brew install cocoapods
zsh: command not found: brew

Comment: First install homebrew and than install cocoapods pods

Comment: Thank you, I’m very noob about mac, i don’t want to make more bad things. Have you a simple command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running this command:

```
sudo arch -arm64e gem install ffi
```

Comment: No, because you are updating the architecture to arm64e, if this did not solve your problem you can run the command agian using -x86_64 replacing arm64e

Comment: OK, it's done. but I have always CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

Exception: CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.

Comment: I need to use sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi ?

Comment: I run sudo gem install cocoapods and   pod repo update it's loading.

Comment: [NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

Comment: What do you get about this bug?

Comment: I don't know, after run  pod repo update
 it stop at   559 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644365/cocoapods-on-m1-apple-silicon-fails-with-ffi-wrong-architecture

Comment: thank you, I try brew uninstall ruby --force but
zsh: command not found: brew

Comment: Ok.. first you need install HomeBrew using this command : /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Comment: now I have dquote>

Comment: I can't run anything

Comment: what do you get?

Comment: nothing just my terminal now start with dquote>

Comment: but I can't run flutter doctor or other command with this dquote>

Comment: OK, I quit android studio and it's normal now

Comment: I don't know if /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh) have done somthing..

Comment: basically that command installs homebrew

Comment: OK, how can I verify that homebrew was well install ? or what can I do after ?

Comment: now when I run pod repo update I have/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/rbconfig.rb:230: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/XXXXX/Developer/flutter/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Updating spec repo `master`
Updating spec repo `trunk`. [!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/deprecated_podspecs.txt Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: I run pod repo remove trunk
I can now run pod repo update
and now I pod is installing

Comment: finally I have some stuck on running, so I create a new flutter projet, to test basic example, it's ok, so I migrate all lib,asset etc and it's ok. By the way, thank you, for the support, this help me to not be crazy ^^