# Troubleshooting CocoaPods Installation on M2 Mac

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Issue installing and running CocoaPods on M2 Mac.

Due to my Mac being a M2 machine, I am unable to install CocoaPods via Gem. I installed CocoaPods via Homebrew but when running pod install I am just getting this error:

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.

I've done some research and many people are suggesting to downgrade the CocoaPods to 1.10.0 or a similar version but I am unable to do this via Homebrew.

Has anyone been able to get CocoaPods running on M2 machines?

Thanks

Comment: "Due to my Mac being a M2 machine, I am unable to install CocoaPods via Gem" That's false. Did you remember to install your own Ruby?

Comment: @matt Thanks for the reply. Correct, I am running ruby 3.2.2. When I try to run pods install with the gem version I get a "Bad CPU type in executable" error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644365/cocoapods-on-m1-apple-silicon-fails-with-ffi-wrong-architecture